# Is $\Omega(n) = O(n \log n)$?

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

problem
$T(n) = 3T(n/4) + n \log n$

$f(n) = n \log n$
and $g(n) = n$

Why is $\Omega(g(n)) = O(n \log n)$?
Is it because $\Omega$ means at some $n$ and constant, $\Omega(g(n)) = O(n \log n)$?

Comment: Why do you think that $\Omega(g(n)) = O(n\log n)$? Some context seems to be missing here.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $n^2 \in \Omega(g(n))$, obviously, $n^2\notin O(n\log n)$ and therefore $\Omega(g(n)) \neq O(n \log n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively: $\Omega(\cdot)$ gives a *lower* bound, $O(\cdot)$ gives an *upper* bound. If I tell you $x > 1$, you can't deduce an upper bound for $x$ from it.